# "Microsoft.Scripting.Math.BigInteger" has been removed from "MMicrosoft.Dynamic.dll" in IronPython 2.7.11

Tags: python, c#, ironpython, biginteger, iron

I have a plan to upgrade Iron Python of my project from V2.3.7 to 2.7.11.
When I am replacing the new IronPython package, I found that "Microsoft.Scripting.Math.BigInteger" has been removed from Microsoft.Dynamic.dll and it makes my code error.
Could you show me where to get BigInteger class to replace or any solution to fix this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Python can natively handle arbitrarily large integers, so there may be no need for Math.BigInteger — perhaps that's why it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger was previously shipped with the [dlr](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr) for older .NET (pre 4.0) versions. Given that IronPython no longer supports those targets, they removed it [quite some time ago](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr/issues/86).

Nowadays you probably want to use [System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) which is supported starting with .NET 4.0.